# Why are there two different methods to create a temporary table in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

In Redshift I can create a temporary table in two different ways.

Using [the `TEMPORARY` parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html#r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW-parameters):

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl...
```

or by putting a hash at the start of the table name:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #tbl...
```

The Redshift docs have a special red **Important** box which describes this other method:

> If you specify a table name that begins with '#', the table is created as a temporary table.

But they don't say *why* these two methods exist, and whether one is preferred over the other for any reason.

I assume the `#tbl` formulation is for historical/backwards compatibility reasons, but it'd be interesting to see what these are.

Answer (score 0):

The '#' syntax for temp tables is used in several other databases (SQL server, MySQL).  Redshift allows this syntax to enable greater tool compatibility and SQL portability.

Here's SQL Server's [documentation for temporary tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#temporary-tables):

> Prefix local temporary table names with single number sign (#table_name), and prefix global temporary table names with a double number sign (##table_name).

Comment: This is an interesting answer. Redshift is a fork of Postgres, so if you can make the same point about Postgres, and if you can link to anything which verifies your claim, I'll accept it!

Comment: AWS / Redshift doesn't officially provide insight into their motivations so I don't expect any documentation of this.   I can provide my personal interactions with AWS employees that confirm this intent but hard proof is unofficial and confidential.  I can point you to the list of non-postgres SQL components in Redshift which in combination supports this position - NVL(), DECODE(), UNLOAD, GETDATE() etc.  These are borrowed from other DBs/SQLs and while some are needed extensions to Postgres from Redshift, others are just handy additions for easy of porting (DECODE & NVL).

Comment: And I guess I can give you one more piece of supporting evidence - Why is Redshift called Redshift?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Redshift  Many of these non-postgres SQL components are from Oracle BTW.

Comment: I've added a link to the SQL Server documentation which mentions the use of `#table_name` for temporary tables, but it looks to me like Oracle uses `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  There are similar links for the other "adopted" SQL pieces mentioned in the comment above.  These can be attached as well if the OP desires.